# Is there a glossary of terms for YouTube's API?

Tags: api, youtube, comments, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to test YouTube's API in conjunction with their comments section, but I have no idea what any of the words, parameters and jargon mean. For example, parent id - what is this exactly?

I'm a complete novice (can you tell?), so I'm simply trying to wrap my head around it all.

In a nutshell, what I'm aiming to achieve is to pull specific YouTube users' comments elsewhere, and, if I'm able to, perhaps the amount of likes its had as well. In other words, if you have an account on my platform, whatever you've commented on YouTube will also display on your page/account on my website.

Is this at all possible with YouTube's API, or any API for that matter??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "glossary" per say, but here is their API documentation
[here is their API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs), and [here is the section specially for the comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments).
Reading up on "Comments: list" it sounds like you can list all comments made by a user so you can then use that information on your site.